# Best way to handle w/ Accents and Spaces in the URL ($_GET)

Tags: php

I need to handle with accents and spaces in $_GET['city'] parameter.

Whats the best way to post and receive it?

http://www.teste.com/?city=São Paulo

Thanks
Luciano

Comment: Do you have control of the other end? the PHP end?

Comment: What you need to do is that ensure that your pages are all UTF compliant. HTML, PHP, everything!! That will solve half of the problem.Make sure even the jeans you are wearing is UTF compliant..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best to use the urlencode() function in PHP before you pass the data over $_GET. Then on the receiving end, use urldecode().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I read in php.net that urldecode() should not be used in $_GET due possibility to MySQL Injection. Is that safe?

Comment: urlencode() and urldecode() just make it so data is URL safe. To prevent MySQL injections, use this function: mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

How about `str_replace()`?

**Send city with**

```
$cityurl = str_replace(' ', '_',$cityurl);//replace spaces with "_"
```

And the link is

```
http://www.teste.com/?city=$cityurl //url is like http://www.teste.com/?city=São_Paulo
```

**Receive city  with**

```
$city = str_replace('_', ' ',$_GET['city']);//replace "_" with spaces
```

Comment: OP is not worried only about spaces(can be easily handled), but the accented non-English characters..